# .NET IQueryable MSSQL and ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wpf, asp.net-web-api

The case is following.

There is DataGrid in WPF app which consumes IQueryable as ItemsSource (apply Filtering, Sorting, Grouping, Aggregations, etc...) we have MSSQL Server DB where the data is stored if from the app we directly connect to DB using EF DbSet<> or ADO.NET Table<> everything is work excellent. We do not want that app has direct access to DB and the purpose is to use WebAPI between them. The DataGrid has its own query generator expressions, the generated query looks like

```
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
.Call System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy(
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
        .Constant<Reports.ReportQuery>(Query(RepoService.Flight)),
        '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[RepoService.Flight,DynamicClass1]>)),
    '(.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[DynamicClass1,DynamicClass2]>)),
'(.Lambda #Lambda3<System.Func`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[DynamicClass2,DynamicClass1],Telerik.Pivot.Core.PivotResultItem]>))
```

As I understand OData is not suitable for our case. What we are trying to do is create our custom IQueryable and IQueryProvider get query expression in provider Execute method to send it to WebAPI which then execute it on DB, send back the result and return that result from provider Execute method.

1) Is this way correct/possible?

2) Are there some existing solutions for this case?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for my issue it is [Remote.LINQ](https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand everything correctly what you might ask but I will give it a try to answer.

If you use a WPF to speak directly to SQL-Server it uses a special protocol via the driver. There are a lot of articles exposing SQL Server savely as there also might be MS Azure hosted SQL Server etc. This just for the case you might think of going back to SQL server.

If you go down the route to implement your backend via WebAPI you want to make sure that you implement alle the backend routes that you need to query the information that you need in your application. 
OData is some sort of query language protocol on top of http. So it implements all the query syntax which you need to rebuild on your own using WebApi.

Nevertheless without seeing any code of you it is pretty hard to spot any errors.
But... this is a tutorial how to query a web service via http client library and show the information in wpf datagrid. It might be to long for including the code here and is pretty easy to google.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/consume-Asp-Net-web-api-using-httpclient-in-wpf/

In a more serious application you want to consider to have some abstractions and layers but at the end of the day you your webAPI via a http client and parse the json into objects and bind it. IQueryable is not for free and needs to be implement unless you consider using OData. I would be easier to implement the things you need for your application and expose these routes explicitly.

Don't know if this answers your quest but it might help to rethink the concept.
If I got you wrong please consider to update your question an be more precise.

HTH